# DAL уровень, некоректная строка подключения

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Работаю с Onion архитектурой приложения. Создал уровни DAL, BLL, SLL, WebApi - для предоставления результатов. Ссылки между проектами присутствуют (BLL содержит ссылку на DAL, SLL содержит ссылки на DAL и BLL, webapi - содержит ссылки на BLL, DAL, SSL) Столкнулся с проблемой подключения к БД. Использую PostgreSQl и EF. Подключаю nuget - package Npgsql.EntityFramework на уровне DAL. Файл App.config выглядит след.образом

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
 <configSections>
 <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
<parameters>
<parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
</parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
<provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
<add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="strConn" providerName="Npgsql" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=******;Password=******;Port=5432;Database=testDb;" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

При применении миграций (Enable-migrations) - выдаёт ошибку, что строка подключения не корректна.

Хотя точно такое же содержимое файла App.config используется когда создаю приложение по типу WebApi или любой отдельный проект типа ClassLibrary(.Net Framework). Попробовал пересоздать проект с архитектурой. только сначала создал уровень DAL и выполнил миграции, всё прошло.Реализовал остальные слои (ссылки на уровне указал), попробовал запустить проект, проблема следующая:
    в коде:

```
public interface IUserrepository
    {
        User GetUserById(int id);
    }

    public class UserRepository : IUserrepository
    {
        private readonly UserContext  _context;

        public UserRepository(UserContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public User GetUserById(int id)
        {
            return _context.Users.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

В методе, где возвращаю пользователя, отображает ошибку.

 **No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information."**
```

Поискав по данной ошибке варианты. нашёл "грязный вариант" как писал автор: 
**var ensureDLLIsCopied = SqlProviderServices.Instance;**

Класс контекста

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public UserContext(): base ("strConn")
    {
        var ensureDLLIsCopied = SqlProviderServices.Instance;
    }
}
```

использую Ninject в webapi - проекте. регистрирую сервисы.

```
 private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.RegisterServiceLayer();
        kernel.RegisterBllLayer();
        kernel.RegisterDalLayer();
    }

    public static void RegisterServiceLayer(this IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
    }

    public static void RegisterBllLayer(this IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IMakeGift>().To<MakeGift>();
    }

    public static void RegisterDalLayer(this IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IUserrepository>().To<UserRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<UserContext>().ToSelf();
    }
```

Как правильно и корректно создать БД (CodeFirst) используя многоуровневую архитектуру?

Comment: `<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />` зачем это в конфиге?

Comment: Эта строка по умолчанию создаётся при установке Npgsql.EntityFramework. я взял весь код подключения к БД. Даже без этой строки, происходит выброс исключения No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name ...

Comment: откуда он возьмет `invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"`, если вы это удалили из конфига?

Comment: Я просто проверял, на данный момент содержимое файла App.config, такое же как я написал в вопросе. Просто дело не совсем в этой строке.

Comment: у вас ошибка `No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'`, там же четко написано `System.Data.SqlClient`, как проблема может быть не в этой сроке, если эта строка из текста ошибки?

Comment: [ассоциация](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18455747/312041)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, суть всего состояло в том, что в файле Web.config требуется настроить подключение к БД в проекте WebApi т.е. на уровне представления (соответственно Npgsql.EntityFramework). В DAL подключить Npgsql.EntityFramework. После этого проект заработал. Почему-то Asp.Net работает именно так в таком случае.